# Biztalk 2010 SQL Adapter wizard window disappears

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, biztalk

I am using a clean install of windows 7, with visual studio 2010(sp1) and biztalk 2010, and SQL Server 2008 R2(sp1). From Visual Studio, when I try to 'Add a Generated Item' and then 'Add Metadata Adapter' for a SQL adapter, the wizard window disappears just before the wizard is complete. Googling online, I found this is often an issue with MSXML, so I installed MSXML 4 but this did not fix the problem. Downloading the Adapter pack and getting new(er) adapters is not an option for me. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: As a side note, I'd try and avoid the SQL adapter (any version of it) at all costs, its quirky at best and does not perform that well in the wild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old sql adapter is not supported with biztalk 2010. You can migrate your old projects to use the new WCF based sql adapter using biztalk adapter pack migration too.